# Is it possible to perform two speech-to-text streams at same time from one account?

Tags: speech-recognition, grpc, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech, google-speech-to-text-api

So, question is on title, I can create speech to text stream to one user and it works nice, but when I try to connect second user, it works bad for all, sometimes it works good for one user, so question is, can I create sppech-to-text stream for two or more users at same time with one GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or each user need start his own project?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create multiple [streaming](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize) threads by using the same `StreamingRecognize()` client, the ones that can be used to send the requests in parallel. You can take a look on [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/1064) and [this](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech/issues/284) Github posts where it is discussed this topic.

I suggest you to try this alternative and verify if you can perform these streaming calls by creating 2 different objects or clients, such as:

```
client = speech.SpeechClient()

responses = client.streaming_recognize()
responses2 = client.streaming_recognize()
```

On the other hand, if you want to make audio recognitions for batch, it is rather recommended to use [synchronous](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/sync-recognize) or [asynchronous](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize) methods.

**Update. Adding an example with multiple threads in python**

```
import io
import os
import copy

from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types

import threading

# Instantiates a client
# The name of the audio file to transcribe
file_name = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'resources',
    <Audio_File_Name>)

#Using same client
client = speech.SpeechClient()

def streaming(thread):

    #Using different clients
    #client = speech.SpeechClient()


    with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as audio_file:

        content = audio_file.read()
        content2 = copy.deepcopy(content) 

        # In practice, stream should be a generator yielding chunks of audio data.
        stream = [content]
        requests = (types.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=chunk)
                                       for chunk in stream)

    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
        sample_rate_hertz=16000,
        language_code='en-US',
        max_alternatives=1,
        enable_automatic_punctuation=True,
        model='video',
        enable_word_time_offsets=True)


    streaming_config = types.StreamingRecognitionConfig(
            config=config,
            interim_results=True)

    # Detects speech in the audio file
    responses = client.streaming_recognize(streaming_config, requests)
    for response in responses:
        for result in response.results:
            print('{}: Transcript: {}'.format(thread, result.alternatives[0].transcript))
            #print('isFinal: {}'.format(result.is_final))

thread1 = threading.Thread(name="thread1", target=streaming, args=('1',))
thread1.start()
thread2 = threading.Thread(name="thread2", target=streaming, args=('2',))
thread2.start()

print(threading.enumerate())
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
exit(0)
```

Comment: thx a lot! I'll try, did second speech clients before, maybe this caused problems, never tried second streaming call to same speech client sounds right.

Comment: I mean tried both methods, new client and new streaming call to existing client, but did them in different threads, not in one function as you show

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Can you show how did you implemented it to have a better reference?

Comment: I tested it now with other user and all seems working, before I tested from same pc in different tabs, strange, no changes to code, seems it's some kind of a bug on socket-io.js or I don't even know, I'll check your idea with requests in one thread someday when  wil have free time